# If $S$ is an non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $S^\perp$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do I prove the following statement:

If $S$ is an non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $S^\perp$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Well, how does one usually prove that a given subset of a vector space is a subspace?

Comment: By using the closed under addition and scalar multiplication. But I am not sure how to make sure of the orthoganlity propery or the fact that the subset is non-empty

Comment: So, write down what "closed under addition" means; then use the definition of $S^{\perp}$ and what you know about properties of inner products to prove closure under addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y \in S^\bot$, i.e. for all $s \in S$ you have $\langle x_1,s \rangle = \langle x_2,s \rangle = 0$, and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Can you show that $\langle x+y,s \rangle = 0$?.

Can you show that $\langle \lambda x,s \rangle = 0$?

Note that the scalar product $\langle .,. \rangle$ is *linear* in both argument that means $$\begin{eqnarray}
  \langle a+b,c \rangle &=& \langle a,c \rangle + \langle b,c \rangle \\
  \langle a,b+c \rangle &=& \langle a,b \rangle + \langle a,c \rangle \\
  \langle \lambda a,b \rangle &=& \lambda \langle a,b \rangle \\
  \langle a,\lambda b \rangle &=& \lambda \langle a,b \rangle 
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Whoever downvoted this - care to explain why?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but maybe someone thinks you gave too much detail on a homework problem, instead of helping OP to work more of it out.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Hm, maybe, though I don't feel I did. What I stated are merely the definitions of orthognality, linearity and subspace. Those are things that the OP wouldn't really be expected to work out, but rather to know or look up. Granted, combining them to produce the answer is rather trivial, but so was the OP's question to begin with. But I'm open for suggestions on how to deal with such questions better...

Comment: Well, I was trying to deal with it by a series of questions in comments to try to draw the answer out of OP.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry if I interfered with that, that wasn't my intention. I merely wanted to state the necessary definitions, so that the OP has a place to start from.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I was just giving a suggestion as to another possible way to work with such questions.